# How did instaEarth create the map on their front page?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've worked with google maps before, but I've never seen anything about being able to embed photos or anything into the markers... Some how http://instaearth.me did...

Does anyone have any references to this feature(s)? I'd like to use some of these features for a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert whole divs with the InfoBox, so here's a quick demo. Pardon the childish image border.

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/

http://jsbin.com/ivuwaq/edit#preview

Click on the map to add a cat icon

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom overlays to add images and html to defined latitude/longitude points on your google map using the API. There's a fairly good reference on how to do it on the [Google Map API Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays). You can also make the overlays show or hide based on marker click events, which is how instaearth.me is probably doing it.